# Ubuntu 14.04 unstable wifi connection with Intel wifi card

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have problem with my Intel wireless card. Connection is very unstable and very often gets lost. I've tried to disable IPv6 settings but it doesn't help.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try this method. http://askubuntu.com/a/663328/167850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WiFi card is working there are two courses of action you can take:

1. You can also verify that you're not using generic drivers for your specific card.

   http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

   Also, Intel has an entire wiki on maintaining drivers for their devices located [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi).
2. You may just have to turn the power up. I know this sounds bad, but unfortunately the drivers for WiFi just aren't that great and unfortunately do not match their Windows counterparts. I experienced this on my box as well.

   Please keep in mind that this can cause excessive heat on your board.

   ```
   sudo iw reg set BO
   sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
   ```

This turns up the power and switches your country to Bolivia.

Comment: I will try your advice if the @Pilot6 tip doesn't help.

Comment: Bolivia? Why Bolivia???

Comment: Ad.2. I don't keen on this method because temperature on my board is sometimes too high.

Comment: Bolivia allows higher power transmissions whereas many other nations regulate it.

Comment: @josh - any news on this?