# Wifi problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, intel-wireless

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my vaio vpccb17fx with Intel Centrino Wireless N1000.
Unfortunately my signal strength is very weak, it keeps disconnecting and actually I can't use Wifi!
I don't know what to do as I'm new to Linux.
I would be very grateful for someone who could help me (and maybe others have the same problem)
Thanks.

Comment: Try this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/663328/167850

Comment: I tried this, but made no difference, so reverted that.

Comment: do you have privative drivers available in additional drivers? you can find this in applications overview.

Comment: Only Additional Driver: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs for intel-microcode, nothing else

Comment: This problem in More in details and solution works<br> https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues/768268#768268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WIFI regulatory domain not set

Set the  [WIFI country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for the Kernels current regulatory domain if it isn't set.

```
iw reg get
```

To set it

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
REGDOMAIN=<ISOCODE>
```

Reboot.

### Upstream kernel

Try the [latest upstream kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). I saw [WIFI bug-reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1578610) that were fixed with a new kernel, so it's worth a try. It also fixed mine. Read more about [upstream kernels here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds).

Download and install the packages that corresponds to your architecture (e.g. AMD64, kernel [4.6-rc7-wily](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-rc7-wily/))

```
linux-headers-4.6.0-040600rc7-generic_4.6.0-040600rc7.201605081830_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.6.0-040600rc7_4.6.0-040600rc7.201605081830_all.deb
linux-image-4.6.0-040600rc7-generic_4.6.0-040600rc7.201605081830_amd64.deb


sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Made no difference, :( I think I should dual boot with Windows so that I can use wifi

Comment: Try the new kernel, i updated my answer.