# Wifi is connected but internet drops after some time

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Internet connection drops after some random amount of time which changes from seconds to 15 minutes. However, wifi is still connected at full strength. I have to disconnect and reconnect every time when this happends. Searched the internet.

- Tried this: [related problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out), lost internet connection completely but I managed to take back what i have done.
- Tried this: [Intel Centrino problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230), no change.

That problem still continues.

How to solve this problem?

Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04

Result from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; iwconfig`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5305]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device [152d:0873]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"No Service"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: FC:4A:E9:38:99:0B   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:69   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Result of `./wireless-info` when internet connection is ok: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21463166/
Result of `./wireless-info` when internet connection is dropped: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21465233/

**Note**: However, this time internet connection came back without reconnecting after a short amount of time.

Comment: Please edit to add what Ubuntu version you are using and results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I edited the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreliable wireless connection with an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230)

Comment: @Pilot6 Tried that one but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) once with a working internet connection and once after the connection was dropped and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the settings on the "No Service" wifi router?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, I have full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the channel your wifi is on as there are 10 access points on channel 1

```
Channel occupancy:
```

```
  10   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
  5   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
  7   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

You can see the wifi channels in use from the script results.  I would also change the SSID to No-Service eliminating the space in the name.

There is a another network with the same name, possibly a guest.  I would change this to No-Service2, giving it a unique name and eliminating the space.  Also change the encryption to match as this one has TKIP enabled

```
Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm

                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"No Service"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000004b54ad8
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm

                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"No Service"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000009216a456e8
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

The issues I saw in your wireless script was a crowded channel 1 and having 2 access points with the same name and your computer was jumping from one to the other

```
[  241.663063] wlan0: authenticate with 
[  241.663537] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  241.665598] wlan0: authenticated
[  241.665740] wlan0: waiting for beacon from 
[  241.927534] wlan0: authenticate with 
[  241.934607] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  241.963944] wlan0: authenticated
[  241.968113] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  241.986164] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
```

The 'No Service' [AC1] is the one with the stronger signal in the script results and the preferred encryption.  'No Service' [AC2] has TKIP encryption enabled.

When those changes are done your wifi may benefit by changing the module parameter with

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: I have a wifi repeater in the house. The second one with the same name is the repeater. I cannot change its name as it uses the same name with the original network. But i will try using another less crowded channel.

Comment: I changed the channel and so far the Internet has dropped only once. That is a great improvement. Thanks.