# Losing wifi internet some of the time

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi connection to my home internet is unable to bring up a website only some of the time. This happens once a week roughly, and after a couple hours it usually comes back.

From everything I have checked so far there appear to be no problems with the connection itself. I can ping websites, and when I do iwconfig it shows my Bit Rate at 54 MB/s.

However when I go to Firefox or Chromium and try and navigate to a website it just says "The connection has timed out" after about 5-10 seconds.

The output from the command lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is:

```
02:00:0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I also tried running the command suggested from this thread [Unreliable wireless connection with an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230)

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

This did not work as well. Currently some pages are able to load a title to the webpage, but both Chromium and Firefox hang just waiting for the website(s) to respond.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Ok, I put that output there, does it show anything unusual?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreliable wireless connection with an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230)

Comment: Nothing unusual ;-). Now we know what is the adapter and how to fix it.

Comment: I ran that command suggested and rebooted. I tried loading a number of different websites, one came up but only after about 2 minutes, another loaded only the title page, and then a few others don't come up at all. At the bottom of the Chromium browser it says "Waiting for *website*...". I am also trying Firefox which has the same issue.

Comment: Then it is not related to Ubuntu. There may be any kind of a network problem.

Comment: I have another laptop connected to the same wifi network running Windows and there is no issue at the moment, while the laptop running 16.04 Ubuntu cannot connect with the problem described.

Comment: No more ideas then, sorry.

Comment: Try disabling IPv6.  I had issues with mine as well and would have to either wait, connect to my other router, or turn the WiFi off and on again.  If you go in the properties of your connection, you can go to the IPv6 tab and set it to ignore.  Worked for me.

Comment: It's a pretty strange issue because now 2 hours later everything connects fine and I did not change anything. Although it's been the 5th or 6th time this has happened where I cannot connect to a websites for a couple hours, wait a few hours, and I am magically able to connect again.