# Recently installed Ubuntu 16.10, but can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, gnome, 16.10

Recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. I can see my wifi network, but when I connect and enter my password it will try to connect, but will ask for my password again and would never connect. My wifi worked in previous versions but refuses to work now. The wifi card is an Intel Centario N2230

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/663328/167850